# Post data info to CGI script using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql

I have this very simple HTML Form. I want to pass the input to a CGI script (Python), which will store them into mysql table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Cadastro</h2>

<form name="cadastro" id="cadastro" action="/cgi-bin/cadastro.py" method="POST">
  <label for="nome">Nome completo:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required><br>
  <label for="mae">Nome completo da mãe:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="mae" name="mae" required><br>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form works great and data is correctly stored into the mysql table.

However, I wanted to make a "successful" message when clicking the submit button, instead of redirecting it to the cgi script.

I believe the easiest way to do that is using javascript. Then, I tried adding this to the code:

```
<script>
  const cadastro = document.getElementById("cadastro");

  cadastro.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("post", "/cgi-bin/cadastro.py")
    request.send();
  });
</script>
```

Here is the python script, in case its necessary:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
import cgi, mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "xxx",
    user = "yyy",
    password = "aaa",
    database = "bbb",
)

cadastro = cgi.FieldStorage()

def add_cliente(nome, mae):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, mae) VALUE (%s, %s)", (nome, mae))
    db.commit()
    return print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

add_cliente(cadastro.getvalue("nome"), cadastro.getvalue("mae"))
```

However, the user input is stored as NULL in the mysql table. Could someone help, please?

Comment: check, if there are values first if cadastro .has_key("name") and cadastro .has_key("mae"):

Comment: You mean check if the table has columns "name" and "mae"? If so, it does. The first code works great. It sends the data correctly to the table. When I use javascript to post, it doesn't.

Comment: no i meant the values from the cgi script  Ok comments are bad to read but the rest of my comment is code

Comment: I believe you mean you want me to set variables for `cadastro.getvalue("nome")` and `cadastro.getvalue("mae")` and use `.has_key` to check if they return True. Right? If so, I believe they are, because posting directly from the HTML Form (first code block) works.

Comment: do it anyway check if there are values  because your mysql code works(you could evemtuyll add erro handling see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html so the variables mae and nome must be empty,l that why i said that you should check it

Comment: I've tried, but I don't know how to proceed with that. :(

Comment: see here where they check https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to the script not sending any data, thus the NULL values. As mentioned, the cgi script was working good.

Here is an example javascript code, extracted from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript):

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function () {
  function sendData() {
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Bind the FormData object and the form element
    const FD = new FormData( form );

    // Define what happens on successful data submission
    XHR.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
      alert( event.target.responseText );
    } );

    // Define what happens in case of error
    XHR.addEventListener( "error", function( event ) {
      alert( 'Oops! Something went wrong.' );
    } );

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open( "POST", "https://example.com/cors.php" );

    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send( FD );
  }

  // Access the form element...
  const form = document.getElementById( "myForm" );

  // ...and take over its submit event.
  form.addEventListener( "submit", function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    sendData();
  } );
} );
```